# Deployment fails on anti-affinity rule with topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname - Required value: can not be empty

Tags: kubernetes

I have an anti-affinity rule that asks kubernetes to schedule pods from the same deployment onto [different nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node), we've used it successfully for a long time.

```
affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: application
          operator: In
          values:
          - {{ $appName }}
        - key: proc  
          operator: In
          values:
          - {{ $procName }}
```

I'm trying to update my pod affinity rules to be a strong preference instead of a hard requirement, so that we don't need to expand our cluster if a deployment needs more replicas than there are nodes available.

```
affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      weight: 100
      labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: application
          operator: In
          values:
          - {{ $appName }}
        - key: proc 
          operator: In
          values:
          - {{ $procName }}
```

However, when I try applying the new rules, I get an unexpected error with the topologyKey:

```
Error: Deployment.apps "core--web" is invalid:
[spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0].podAffinityTerm.topologyKey: Required value: can not be empty,
spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0].podAffinityTerm.topologyKey: Invalid value: "": name part must be non-empty,
spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0].podAffinityTerm.topologyKey: Invalid value: "": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyName',  or 'my.name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]')]
```

The scheduler seems to be getting an empty string value for the topology key, even though all my nodes have a label for the specified key which match the regex:

```
$ kubectl describe nodes | grep kubernetes.io/hostname
kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal
kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal
kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal
kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal
```

I didn't expect to see a problem like this from a simple change from required to preferred.  What did I screw up to cause the topologyKey error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a slight difference between the syntax of required and preferred, note the reference to `podAffinityTerm` in the error message path:

```
spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0].podAffinityTerm.topologyKey
```

The correct syntax for preferred scheduling is:

```
affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 100
      podAffinityTerm:
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: application
            operator: In
            values:
            - {{ $appName }}
          - key: proc
            operator: In
            values:
            - {{ $procName }}
```

Note that `weight` is a top level key, with a sibling of `podAffinityTerm` which contains the `topologyKey` and `labelSelector`.

Comment: Thanks. I had this exact problem trying to figure out the syntax for `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`. However, when I describe deployment and pod I don't see any mention of `Affinity` or `podAntiAffinity` is that expected?

Comment: @Justin It doesn't look like the defined affinity rules are included in the `kubectl describe` output, but you can see them using `kubectl get <pod/deployment> <name> -o yaml`.